# Why the compare between two LocalDate variables doesn't work?

Tags: java, localdate

I've created an ArrayList of type Flight in Main class.Also Flight is a class that contains LocalDate variable , getters and setters. In main I created a boolean flag theDay and setted to true. I want this flag to change in false when the For loop find a LocalDate day value as the same before.
For example:

1st Try: I putted the value 3 into scanner.nextInt(); 
     It printed 2019-5-3 and "Didn't found a same date."

2nd Try: I putted the value 6 into scanner.nextInt();
     It printed 2019-5-6 and "Didn't found a same date."

3rd Try: I putted the value 3 again into scanner.nextInt();
     It printed 2019-5-3 and "Didn't found a same date."
     I was expected to get a message of "A same date found".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Flight> flightList = new ArrayList<Flight>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int counter=1;
    while (counter <= 3) {
        Flight flight = new Flight();

        System.out.println("Give the day of the departure.");

        LocalDate day = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MAY, scanner.nextInt());
        flight.setDateOfDeparture(day);

        System.out.println(flight.getDateOfDeparture());

        boolean theDay = true; //Flag (reversed way in order to achieve the TRUE logic value).
        for (Flight flight1 : flightList) {
            System.out.println(flight1.getDateOfDeparture());

            if (flight1.getDateOfDeparture().compareTo(flight.getDateOfDeparture()) == 0) {
                theDay = false;
            }
        }

        counter++;

        if (theDay){
            System.out.println("Didn't found a same day.");
        }else
            System.out.println("A same date found");
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be simpler with a [mcve] to show the value that you are comparing. It seems your `flightList` is empty... so there is nothing to compare.

Comment: where do you add `flight` to your `flightList` ? It is always empty.

Comment: Ok, what you want is to add in the `if` block `flightList.add(flight1)` to add the flight only if no date was found. That way, the output should match your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never add any instance in your list.
Based on your expectations :

- 1st Try: I putted the value 3 into `scanner.nextInt();` It printed `2019-5-3` and `"Didn't found a same date."`
- 2nd Try: I putted the value
  6 into `scanner.nextInt();` It printed `2019-5-6` and `"Didn't found a same date."`
- 3rd Try: I putted the value 3 again into
  `scanner.nextInt();` It printed `2019-5-3` and `"Didn't found a same date."` **I was expected to get a message of "A same date found".**

What you need is to insert a `flight` when the `theDay` is true, when there is no departure date already matching.

```
if (theDay){
    flightList.add(flight);
    System.out.println("Didn't found a same day.");
}else{
    System.out.println("A same date found");
}
```

---

**When you are ready to move forward, you could use a `Set<Flight>` with a correct equivalence implementation**

You will never need to check yourself if there is already an "equivalent" instance, the `Set` will do it for you.

All you need is to implement `equals` and `hashCode` correctly and your code will simply look like :

```
Set<Flight> flights = new HashSet<>();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    Flight f = new Flight();
    f.setDeparture(LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MAY, sc.nextInt()));

    if(flights.add(f)){
        System.out.println("New flight added");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Flight already booked");
    }
}

sc.close();
```

And to give you an idea, here is the generated methods by eclipse for a simple class

```
class Flight {
    LocalDate departure;

    public void setDeparture(LocalDate departure) {
        this.departure = departure;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((departure == null) ? 0 : departure.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Flight other = (Flight) obj;
        if (departure == null) {
            if (other.departure != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!departure.equals(other.departure))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again! I will notice what you commented before in order to create more readable texts.

Comment: You are welcome @MikePanrs, I have added a sample with a `Set`, if you are new, don't bother with it, it might be a bit complex for the moment, but remember to check other `Collection` than `List` at some point.

Comment: The entire body of that hashCode() method can be replaced with [return Objects.hashCode(departure);](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object%29).  The  portion of the equals method after the assignment of `Flight other` can be replaced with [return Objects.equals(this.departure, other.departure);](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you do not add your flight to your `flightList` so it is always empty.
Change your code to add the flight when there is not date found, in your if statement:

```
if (theDay){
      System.out.println("Didn't found a same day.");
      flightList.add(flight);
} else {
      System.out.println("A same date found");
}
```